# Installing LAPACK and BLAS Libraries for C on Mac OS

Tags: c, installation, lapack, blas

I wanted instructions/websites from where I could download LAPACK and BLAS libraries for use in my C programs. I also wanted to know how I could link these to the gcc compiler from terminal.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) to take care of this for you. Just install Homebrew and then:

```
brew install openblas
brew install lapack
```

But you don't even need that: macOS already ships with BLAS and LAPACK implementations in its [vecLib framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/veclib). So if your software is vecLib-aware, or you pass it the right compiler options, you don't even need to install a separate BLAS and LAPACK.

Comment: What are the right compiler options?

Comment: Depends on your computer configuration and application, I think. The point of Homebrew is that it takes care of the compiler options for you, for common use cases. If you have a specialized use case, then the right compiler options may depend on your particular environment and use case.